# Generating heatmap using pylab

Tags: python, ipython, matplotlib, heatmap

I got a 2d array of data which i would like to plot as a heatmap using pylab. I only found solutions to use normal points to build a heatmap but not a way to map `f(x,y) = heat` onto a heatmap.

PS: ipython is awesome to do such stuff in combination with pylab :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out its fairly easy:

```
import pylab as pl
data = pl.random((25,25)) # 25x25 matrix of values
pl.pcolor(data)
pl.colorbar()
pl.show()
```

Comment: why there are white spaces when we use for example data = pl.random((24,21)) ?